# How to limit blank space in the input field?

Tags: php, html, mysqli

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>  
<html>
<head>
<style>
.error {
    color:red;
}

.button {
     background-color: #4CAF50;
     border: none;
     color: white;
     padding: 10px 25px;
     text-align: center;
     text-decoration: none;
     display: inline-block;
     font-size: 16px;
     margin: 4px 2px;
     cursor: pointer;
 }
 .div1 {
     background-color: #f2f2f2;
     margin-top: -19px;
     margin-bottom: -25px;
     margin-left: -19px; 
 }

 .copy {
     border-radius: 4px;
     padding: 6px 20px;
     border-style: ridge;
 }

 .copy1{
     border-radius: 4px;
     padding: 6px 28px;
     border-style: ridge;
 }

 .copy2{
     border-radius: 4px;
     padding: 4px 2px;
 }

     </style>
     </head>
     <body>  


                    <?php
                    session_start();
                    if (isset($_SESSION['id'])){
                                header('location:welcome.php');
                        } 
                        ?>


                <?php
                // define variables and set to empty values
                include_once 'connect.php';

                $nameErr = $emailErr = $usernameErr = $passwordErr = $DateOfBirthErr = $departmentErr = $ageErr = $fileToUploadErr = $fileToUploadErrr = $fileToUploadErrrr = $fileToUploadErrrrr = $fileToUploadErrrrrr = "" ;
                $name = $email = $username = $password = $DateOfBirth = $department = $age = $fileToUpload = $filename = $file = "";

                if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
                  if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
                    $nameErr = "Name is required";
                  } else {
                    $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
                    // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
                    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
                      $nameErr = "Only letters"; 
                    }
                  }

                   if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
                    $emailErr = "Email is required";
                  } else {
                    $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
                    // check if e-mail address is well-formed
                    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
                      $emailErr = "Invalid email format"; 
                    }
                  }

                  if (empty($_POST["username"])) {
                    $usernameErr = "Username is required";
                  } else {
                    $username = test_input($_POST["username"]);
                     // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
                    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$username)) {
                      $usernameErr = "Only letters"; 
                    }
                  }

                  if (empty($_POST["password"])) {
                    $passwordErr = "Password is required";
                  } else {
                    $password = test_input($_POST["password"]);
                    $hashed_password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
                    // check weather password is alphanumeric
                  if(!preg_match('/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Za-z])[0-9A-Za-z!@#$%]{6,}$/', $password))
                  {
                    $passwordErr = "Password must be alphanumeric and atleast 6 characters long!";
                  }
                  }

                   if (empty($_POST["Date_of_birth"])) {
                    $DateOfBirthErr = "Date Of Birth is required";
                  } else {
                    $DateOfBirth = test_input($_POST["Date_of_birth"]);
                  }

                  if (empty($_POST["department"])) {
                    $departmentErr = "Department is required";
                  } else {
                    $department = test_input($_POST["department"]);
                  }

                   if (empty($_POST["age"])) {
                    $ageErr = "Age is required";
                  } else {
                    $age = test_input($_POST["age"]);
                  }

                        //UPLOAD FILE
                        $uploaddir = 'upload/';
                        $uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['fileToUpload']['name']);
                        $imageFileType = pathinfo($uploadfile,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

                        if($_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'] != '')
                        {  
                            // Check the image is actaully image or not
                            $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
                            if($check == false) 
                            {
                                $fileToUploadErrrrr = "File is not an image.";

                            } 

                            // Check if file already exists
                            if (file_exists($uploadfile)) {
                                $fileToUploadErrrrrr = "Sorry, file already exists.";
                            }

                                if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" ) 
                                {
                                        $fileToUploadErr = "Sorry, only JPG,PNG files are allowed.";
                                }


                                elseif($_FILES['fileToUpload']['size'] > 500000) 
                                {

                                $fileToUploadErrrr = "Sorry, your file is too large.";

                                }

                                else
                                {   
                                      /*  if($filename != '')
                                        {
                                                $target = "upload/".$filename;
                                                unlink($target);
                                        }*/

                                        $uploaded = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile);
                                        if ($uploaded) {
                                                $file = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'];
                                        }   
                                        else{
                                                $file = $filename;
                                        }
                                }
                        }

                        elseif($_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'] = " ")
                        {

                            $fileToUploadErrr = "Please Select an image!";

                        }

                        else {
                                $file = $filename;
                        }



                if($nameErr == "" && $emailErr == "" && $usernameErr == "" && $passwordErr == "" && $fileToUploadErr == "" && $fileToUploadErrr == "" && $fileToUploadErrrr == "" && $fileToUploadErrrrr == "" && $fileToUploadErrrrrr == "" )
                  { 
                $check="SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$_POST[username]'";
                $rs = mysqli_query($mysqli,$check);
                $da = mysqli_fetch_array($rs, MYSQLI_NUM);
                if($da[0] > 0) {
                    echo "Username Already in Exists<br/>";
                }

                else
                {
                    $sql = "INSERT INTO users(`userid`,`username`, `password`, `email` , `name` , `Date_of_birth` , `department` ,`age` , `filename` )
                             VALUES ('','".$username."', '".$hashed_password."', '".$email."' , '".$name."' , '".$DateOfBirth."' , '".$department."' , '".$age."' , '".$file."')";

                        if (mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql)) {
                        echo "Registered successfully";
                        } else {
                        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($mysqli);
                        } 
                        mysqli_close($mysqli);
                }
                  }
                }

                function test_input($data) {
                  $data = trim($data);
                  $data = stripslashes($data);
                  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
                  return $data;
                }
                ?>

                <div style="padding-left: 250px" class="div1">

                    <h2 style="color:#009999">Registration Form :</h2>
                    <p><span class="error">All fields are required </span></p>
                    <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                            <span style="color:#0099ff">Name: </span>
                            <input type="text" name="name" class= "copy" style="margin-left: 52px"  value ="<?php 
                                     if (isset($name)) 
                                      echo $name; 
                                 ?>">
                            <span class="error"> <?php echo $nameErr;?></span>
                            <br><br>

                            <span style="color:#0099ff"> E-mail: </span>
                            <input type="text" name="email" class= "copy" style="margin-left: 48px"  value ="<?php 
                                     if (isset($email)) 
                                      echo $email; 
                                 ?>">
                            <span class="error"><?php echo $emailErr;?></span>
                            <br><br>

                            <span style="color:#0099ff"> Username: </span>
                            <input type="text" name="username"  class= "copy" style="margin-left:26px"  value ="<?php 
                                     if (isset($username)) 
                                      echo $username; 
                                 ?>">
                            <span class="error"> <?php echo $usernameErr;?></span>
                            <br><br>

                            <span style="color:#0099ff"> Password: </span>
                            <input type="password" name="password"  class= "copy" style="margin-left:30px">
                            <span class="error"> <?php echo $passwordErr;?></span>
                            <br><br>

                            <span style="color:#0099ff"> Date Of Birth : </span>
                            <input type="date" class= "copy1" name="Date_of_birth"  value ="<?php 
                                     if (isset($DateOfBirth)) 
                                      echo $DateOfBirth; 
                                 ?>">
                            <span class="error"> <?php echo $DateOfBirthErr;?></span>
                            <br><br>

                            <span style="color:#0099ff">  Age : </span>
                            <input type="number" name="age"  class= "copy" style="margin-left:62px"  value ="<?php 
                                     if (isset($age)) 
                                      echo $age; 
                                 ?>">
                            <span class="error"> <?php echo $ageErr;?></span>
                            <br><br>

                            <span style="color:#0099ff">  Department : </span>
                            <select name="department"  class= "copy2" style="margin-left:14px"  value ="<?php 
                                     if (isset($department)) 
                                      echo $department; 
                                 ?>">
                                    <option value="EE">Electrical & Electronics</option>
                                    <option value="EC">Electronics & Communication</option>
                                    <option value="ME">Mechanical</option>
                                    <option value="CS">Computer Science</option>
                                    <option value="CV">Civil</option>
                                    <option value="IS">Information Science</option>
                            </select>
                            <span class="error"> <?php echo $departmentErr;?></span>
                            <br><br>

                            <span style="color:#0099ff">  Select image : </span>
                            <input type="file" name="fileToUpload">
                            <?php if($filename !=''){ ?> <img src="<?php  echo "upload/" .$filename ?>" style="width:180px;height:100px;padding:10px;"/> <?php } ?>
                            <span class="error"><br> <?php echo $fileToUploadErr; ?></span>
                            <span class="error"><br> <?php echo $fileToUploadErrr; ?></span>
                            <span class="error"><br> <?php echo $fileToUploadErrrr; ?></span>
                            <span class="error"><br> <?php echo $fileToUploadErrrrr; ?></span>
                            <span class="error"><br> <?php echo $fileToUploadErrrrrr; ?></span>

                            <input type="submit" class="button" name="submit" value="Register">  
                            <p style="color:black">Already Registered? <a href="login.php">Login</a>.</p>

                        </form>
                </div>
                </body>
                </html>
```

Hi, guys I have only one small issue please help me, I have a registration form with the various input, 
my problem is if I give blank space to the name input field and then if I give submit then it should 
show any error that no space are allowed
i.e., their should be only letters except that it should not accept any numbers special characters and other thing please.
Can any one help me in this please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line `if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {` must be like this:

```
if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]*$/",$name)) {
```

Explanation:

> Your regex has a *space at the end.* Removing it will solve your problem.